# How to set the mean function's form of Gaussian Process using sklearn module in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian

I want to compare the difference of prediction error between linear mean process and the polynomial mean function using the `sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor`. However, only the parameter `normalize_y` is related to the mean process. So, my question is how to set the form of the mean function using `sklearn`  module?

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand what you're asking, but if I understood correctly, won't using different kernels solve your issue?